# SQL Server Management Studio Window Cropped

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am having an issue with the SQL Server Management Studio, hiding some text on a Window. I am using SQL Server 2019. Example below when trying to partition a table using the Wizard.

[image]

The image below shows is what I can see. There're two checkboxes that I am not able to see, whether the window is maximized or not. I changed to different screen resolutions and still no success.

[image]

Comment: Not very clear about what you want to do. Please add more descriptions.

Comment: What is your screen resolution ? Perhaps you need to increase it

Comment: The Create Partition Wizard's window is resizable. You can drag the top/left/bottom/right sides of it with the mouse cursor to make it bigger so you can see all the text.